# Rails 3 ':reject_if => lambda' prevents validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Following [this RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) for nested model forms:

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

and

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :survey
  has_many :answers, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
  validates_presence_of :content
end
```

and

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  validates_presence_of :content
end
```

These are used to create a nested form with all 3 models.

Here's the issue:
I can create a new survey, give the survey a title, leave the question content blank, add an answer and click submit.

The survey gets created. Because of the lambda, the blank question field is discarded as well as the not-blank answer field.

What can I do to make the validation catch when an answer is present but not a question, allowing the user to either delete the answer or provide a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to remove the `:reject_if` when specifying the nested attribute.

Or if you need more flexibility, you can update the lambda to do more things, for example: to reject if both question and answer are empty.

Also look at the [revised source code](https://github.com/railscasts/196-nested-model-form-part-1/tree/master/revised) in github, which is helpful

Comment: Wow, the revised source code with CoffeeScript is a life saver! I was still struggling with the jQuery.

Comment: It appears RBates removed the :reject_if altogether. I will have to test and see if this allows validation. I'll be back to give you that green check mark if all goes well.

Comment: Yep. That works. It's now validating as expected. Way to go Rails 3.